# Mapping Fields based on unknown relationship

Tags: sql-server

I have a challenging SQL query to work out (SQL Server).
I have one table that will show mappings between the two tables.
So below, field F1 is a scanner id

[image]

and table two, has the scanner Id in F1. F2 has the Location, and so on.

[image]

The top table can be updated to change mappings at any time.
So my question is how do I create a query so I know what field name relates to what data in table two.

I started off with an UNPIVOT, but didn't get too far as yet. If I could get the field name in the unpivot results then I am a long way to solving it.

```
SELECT ID, Data
FROM
(
select
ID,[F1] ,[F2]  ,[F3]  ,[F4]  ,[F5]  ,[F6]  ,[F7]  ,[F8]  ,[F9] ,[F10]
FROM [Inventory].[dbo].[ScannedDataCapture]

) AS cp
UNPIVOT 
(
Data FOR Datas IN ([F1] ,[F2]  ,[F3]  ,[F4]  ,[F5]  ,[F6]  ,[F7]  ,[F8]  ,[F9] ,[F10])
) AS x
```

Thanks upfront. Scott

Comment: Did you try using dynamic SQL?

Comment: Its a consideration certainly. I may try also to hit it as the C# end (source input) Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `FOR XML PATH` to help construct a dynamic query:

```
-- Generate a list of field names to be used in the SELECT statement
DECLARE @Sql VARCHAR(MAX) =
(
    SELECT '[' + FieldNumber + '] AS [' + FieldName + '],'
    FROM Datas
    ORDER BY FieldName DESC -- Sample column ordering
    FOR XML PATH('')
)

-- Generate a SELECT query; make sure to remove the comma after the last field
SET @Sql = 'SELECT ' + SUBSTRING(@Sql,1, LEN(@Sql) - 1) + ' FROM dbo.ScannedDataCapture'

-- Show SQL before execution
PRINT @Sql
EXEC sp_sqlexec @Sql
```

[image: Screenshot of dynamic query output]

Comment: that will worked perfect. Thanks for your advice. Scott